# Why do I need to use spread function in axios.all callback?

Tags: javascript, httprequest, axios

I want to send multiple requests using Axios library. So, according to [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axiosspreadcallback), I can do it with `all` method. This is the example:

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete 
  }));
```

But why do I need to write

```
.then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete 
  }));
```

instead of

```
.then(function (acct, perms) {
        // Both requests are now complete 
      });
```

if it also works fine?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `axios.spread` because it's used to spread the array of arguments into multiple arguments. This prevents errors when you are making multiple ajax requests with `axios.all`.

```
axios.all([
 axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/abc');
 axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/abc/repos')
])
.then(axios.spread(function (userResponse, reposResponse) {
  console.log('User', userResponse.data);
  console.log('Repositories', reposResponse.data);
}));
```

Comment: So, what can happen with my AJAX-requests if I don't use `spread`?

Comment: I'm not an expert in axios specifically, but an array isn't a valid input for an argument I'd suspect.

Comment: I'm not an expert in axios specifically, but an array isn't a valid input for a argument I'd suspect.

Comment: What if we don't know the number of number of axios requests? How will we get the response in axios.spread function in this case?